# SQL query to aggregate on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database scheme:

infos (id: int, date: date, provider_id: int)

provider(id: int, type: int, name: varchar)

On any given date, I allow up to 5 different providers each having a different type. What I want is something like this:

DATE | provider.name with type = 0 | .... | ... | PROVIDER.name with type = 4 |

If there is no provider with the correct type on the specified date, then there should be a null value.

I'm struggling to get this setup correctly and would like to avoid doing it later on in my php program (like looping over all results and then aggregating them there, which is possible but seems to be ugly).

I'm using MySQL btw.

Comment: What if the tables contain multiple records for a given `(date, type)` pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do this with a simple join and aggregation:

```
select i.date,
       max(case when p.type = 1 then p.name end) as Type1,
       max(case when p.type = 2 then p.name end) as Type2,
       max(case when p.type = 3 then p.name end) as Type3,
       max(case when p.type = 4 then p.name end) as Type4
from infos i left outer join
     provider p
     on i.provider_id = p.id
group by i.date
```

Comment: Grouping by date does not handle multiple records correctly. It will choose the first providor on that date that meets the type. So if you have 2 providers with type of 4... how will we gurantee the one we want?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying that for more than a few hours now, seems that I'll have to read more into SQL in the future!

Comment: @Shawn . . . First, the question explicitly states "5 different providers each having a different type".  Second, it says nothing about which one should be chosen, if there were multiples which there aren't.  Third, the stated syntax returns the maximum value, not the first value.

Comment: Well, changing it to 5 is not difficult and my application makes sure that there are never two providers with the same type at the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. MySQL syntax could be bit different.

```
select 
(select convert(varchar,infos.date) + provider.name + 'with type = 0'
infos  LEFT JOIN provider
on infos.id = provide.id
and provider.type = 0 and infos.date= inputdate) +
(select provider.name + 'with type = 1'
infos  LEFT JOIN provider
on infos.id = provide.id
and provider.type = 1 and infos.date= inputdate) +
(select provider.name + 'with type = 2'
infos  LEFT JOIN provider
on infos.id = provide.id
and provider.type = 2 and infos.date= inputdate) +
(select provider.name + 'with type = 3'
infos  LEFT JOIN provider
on infos.id = provide.id
and provider.type = 3 and infos.date= inputdate) +
(select provider.name + 'with type = 4'
infos  LEFT JOIN provider
on infos.id = provide.id
and provider.type = 4 and infos.date= inputdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't use MySQL, but in TSQL I would do smth like this:

```
select
  date, type_0, ..., type_n
from
(
  select
    i.date, p.type, p.name
  from infos i
  left join provider p on
    i.provider_id = p.id
) as source
pivot
(
  min(source.name)
  for source.type in (0, 1, ..., n)
) as pivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly PHP is your best bet here because of all the cases you have to handle. You can have multiple rows for each providor OR if there is only one provider then you can have many that match on date and type. PHP form:

```
for($i=0; i<5; $i++)
{
   $list[] = $query->execute("SELECT name FROM query_here WHERE type=$i");
}
```

Now you can use the array to display the data you need.